# upload x bytes using ftp/http

Tags: ftp, curl, http, upload

Is it possible to upload a specific number of bytes (binary data) to http/ftp server using linux command?

Comment: what is the purpose from uploading just bytes no matter of file size to ftp server ?

Comment: I need just to get some statistics

Comment: you want to make a traffic load on remote server for statistics ?
if that there is many tools to make the test

Answer (score 0):

Sure; here's one way with FTP:

```
put "|dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=100" /dev/null
```

Adjust the block size and counts to the amount you need.